# Does Spock plugin support in grails 3.0.5

Tags: grails, spock, grails-3.0

I am new to use this spock plugin.So want to know about spock which version is supported by Grails 3.0.5. Actually using groovy 2.4.4 version.

Please help me out.

Comment: The docs cover testing (with spock and geb) reasonably well.  http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.5/guide/testing.html

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to know spock version? It is bundled in the grails so no need to configure it. Just create new test using some of grails commands like `grails create-unit-test` or create domain or controller and test for it will be created.
Basic dependencies for spock tests are added when creating new application/plugin (`testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"`). In your case grails will use this spock: `org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4` but again you don't need to worry about.

Comment: Mean no need of spock plugin in grails 3.0.5.

Comment: Actually i want to do integration testing.

Comment: Yes, spock is already added to the grails and no need for additional plugin.

Comment: Integration testing are also based on spock, so the same situation - no need for any other plugin.